# Angular, Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(value: any) => void'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-input

I'm passing a value to an `@Input()` in angular,
but somehow this is not working and I do not understand what I'm doing wrong

```html
<my-component
  [foo]="bar"
></my-component>
```

```js
  private _foo = ''
  @Input() foo(value: any) {
    this._foo = value?.toString() || ''
  }
```

Does somebody see my error ?

the error

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(value: any) => void'.
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the offending line? What is `bar` in the consuming component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a setter for your input:

```
  private _foo = ''
  @Input() set foo(value: any) {
    this._foo = value?.toString() || ''
  }
```

Comment: Damn me '-_-. 

Thx a lot !